# How to fetch from an object that is inside arary of array

Tags: javascript, loops

I want to access: **order_items > items > order_item_name**

```
{
    "order_id": 14858,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "date_created": "2020-05-17 07:31:42",
    "date_created_gmt": "2020-05-17 07:31:42",
    "status": "wc-completed",
    "customer_id": 9,
    "customer": {
        "customer_id": 9,
        "user_id": 3,
        "username": "husam",
        "first_name": "Hosam",
        "last_name": "amazon",
        "email": "ecommerce@amazonfoods.ae",
    },
    "order_items": [
        {
            "order_item_id": 152,
            "order_id": 14858,
            "product_id": 9095,
            "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
            "item": {
                "order_item_id": 152,
                "order_item_name": "Amazon Cheddar Cheese, 50g",
                "order_item_type": "line_item",
                "order_id": 14858
            }
        },
        {
            "order_item_id": 153,
            "order_id": 14858,
            "product_id": 9063,
            "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
            "item": {
                "order_item_id": 153,
                "order_item_name": "Amazon 1121 Golden Sella Rice, 5kg",
                "order_item_type": "line_item",
                "order_id": 14858
            }
        },
        
    ]
},
```

Since it is in the loop and can be seen here:

```
const ordersTest = [];
for (let i = 0; i < props.allOrdersState.length && 
    props.allOrdersState.length; i++) {
    ordersTest.push({
        state:props.allOrdersState.length ? props.allOrdersState[i]['customer']['state'] :'',
        first_name:props.allOrdersState.length ? props.allOrdersState[i]['customer']['first_name'] :'',
        orderItems: [{ 
            itemName:props.allOrdersState.length ? props.allOrdersState[i]['order_items'][i]['item']['order_item_name'] :'',  
        }],
    });
}
```

I want to access the order_item_name but it gives an error of undefined. however, the first name and other details can be accessed.

Comment: The order items you are calling is based on your index. So after a certain index you may not have order items. Maybe this is giving you undefined?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like each order has multiple orderItems, so I assume you are trying to map them? The length conditionals weren't needed since the for loop would not have run if length equaled 0. Also, there is no "state" property so I changed it to "status".

```
for (let i = 0; i < props.allOrdersState.length; i++) {      
    ordersTest.push({
        status: props.allOrdersState[i]['status'], 
        first_name: props.allOrdersState[i]['customer']['first_name'], 
        orderItems: props.allOrdersState[i].order_items.map((oi) => ({ 
            itemName: oi['item']['order_item_name']
        }))
    })
}
```

```js
const props = {
    allOrdersState: [
        {
            "order_id": 14858,
            "parent_id": 0,
            "date_created": "2020-05-17 07:31:42",
            "date_created_gmt": "2020-05-17 07:31:42",
            "status": "wc-completed",
            "customer_id": 9,
            "customer": {
                "customer_id": 9,
                "user_id": 3,
                "username": "husam",
                "first_name": "Hosam",
                "last_name": "amazon",
                "email": "ecommerce@amazonfoods.ae",
            },
            "order_items": [
                {
                    "order_item_id": 152,
                    "order_id": 14858,
                    "product_id": 9095,
                    "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
                    "item": {
                        "order_item_id": 152,
                        "order_item_name": "Amazon Cheddar Cheese, 50g",
                        "order_item_type": "line_item",
                        "order_id": 14858
                    }
                },
                {
                    "order_item_id": 153,
                    "order_id": 14858,
                    "product_id": 9063,
                    "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
                    "item": {
                        "order_item_id": 153,
                        "order_item_name": "Amazon 1121 Golden Sella Rice, 5kg",
                        "order_item_type": "line_item",
                        "order_id": 14858
                    }
                },
                
            ]
        }
    ]
}

const ordersTest = [];

for (let i = 0; i < props.allOrdersState.length; i++) {      
    ordersTest.push({
        status: props.allOrdersState[i]['status'], 
        first_name: props.allOrdersState[i]['customer']['first_name'], 
        orderItems: props.allOrdersState[i].order_items.map((oi) => ({ 
            itemName: oi['item']['order_item_name']
        }))
    })
}

console.log(ordersTest)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution is near to what i needed but I have already figured out the issue and displayed the required data .

Your solution is great

Answer (score 0):

You can use the recursive method to find the fields you want.

```
let answer = [];
function indexOf(obj, to) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(to)) {
        answer.push(obj[to]);
    } else if(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Object]') {
        Object.values(obj).filter(item => typeof (item) === 'object').map(item => {
            let newObj = item;
            indexOf(newObj, to);
        })
    } else if(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]') {
        obj.map(item=>{
            let newObj = item;
            indexOf(newObj, to);
            
        })
    }
    return answer;
}
```

My method is a little lax, but it's OK to meet your requirements.

```js
const obj = {
    "order_id": 14858,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "date_created": "2020-05-17 07:31:42",
    "date_created_gmt": "2020-05-17 07:31:42",
    "status": "wc-completed",
    "customer_id": 9,
    "customer": {
        "customer_id": 9,
        "user_id": 3,
        "username": "husam",
        "first_name": "Hosam",
        "last_name": "amazon",
        "email": "ecommerce@amazonfoods.ae",
    },
    "order_items": [
        {
            "order_item_id": 152,
            "order_id": 14858,
            "product_id": 9095,
            "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
            "item": {
                "order_item_id": 152,
                "order_item_name": "Amazon Cheddar Cheese, 50g",
                "order_item_type": "line_item",
                "order_id": 14858
            }
        },
        {
            "order_item_id": 153,
            "order_id": 14858,
            "product_id": 9063,
            "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
            "item": {
                "order_item_id": 153,
                "order_item_name": "Amazon 1121 Golden Sella Rice, 5kg",
                "order_item_type": "line_item",
                "order_id": 14858
            }
        },

    ]
};
let answer = [];
function indexOf(obj, to) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(to)) {
        answer.push(obj[to]);
    } else if(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Object]') {
        Object.values(obj).filter(item => typeof (item) === 'object').map(item => {
            let newObj = item;
            indexOf(newObj, to);
        })
    } else if(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]') {
        obj.map(item=>{
            let newObj = item;
            indexOf(newObj, to);
            
        })
    }
    return answer;
}
console.log(indexOf(obj, 'order_item_name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the issue. I pushed the orderItems along with firstName and other details to the empty array(ordersTest = [];) and all the items moved to the array and then I accessed each item details and order details from the array.

`````
for (let i = 0; i < props.allOrdersState.length && 
props.allOrdersState.length; i++) {
ordersTest.push({
state:props.allOrdersState.length ? props.allOrdersState[i]['customer']['state'] :'',
first_name:props.allOrdersState.length ? props.allOrdersState[i]['customer']['first_name'] :'',
orderItems: [{ 
 itemName:props.allOrdersState.length ? props.allOrdersState[i]['order_items']:'',  
        }],
    });
}````


Then I accessed each element like: 

            {row.itemName.map((historyRow) => (
                  <div style={{border:'1px solid #041e41',padding:'10px'}}>
                   <Typography>{historyRow.item.order_item_name}</Typography> 
                   <Typography gutterBottom component="div">
                   <strong> Shipment Amount:</strong> {historyRow.shipping_amount}
                   </Typography>
                   <Typography>
                  <strong> product Quantity:</strong> {historyRow.product_qty}
                   </Typography>
                   <Typography>
                   <strong>Tax Amount:</strong> {historyRow.tax_amount}
                   </Typography>
                   </div>
                  ))}


I have mapped over row because I am mapping rows of the table and inside each row i have take collapsed of material UI, so each row contains single record: 

  <TableBody>
        {ordersTest.map((row) => (
          <Row key={row.order_id} row={row} />
        ))}
      </TableBody>


And in each single record I am fetching detials and there is again loop over items.
`````